# Is there anyway to append Geo nodes so I can use powerful nodes in different projects?

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, project

I have one big file with a bunch of useful Geo node setups, I feel dumb for asking, but am I able to group the set of nodes and append them like I am able to with shader nodes?

Comment: Hello ! Do you mean *append* ? If yes, you can do it like shader nodes, in fact if you use the append tool, the GN trees will be located in the same folder as the shader trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gorgious commented, you can choose "File" -> "Append", then you choose your blend file and in the directories you click "Nodetree", then choose "your" nodetree.

[image]

After that you can choose it in your GeometryNodes Panel like this:

[image]